# Laravel Routes same base path

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

On Larave 7, I have routes with same path prefix :

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Parking Routes
    |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    Route::resource('parkings', 'Api\Parking\ParkingController');
    Route::get('parkings/filters', 'Api\Parking\ParkingFilterController');
```

In this way, `parkings/filters` returns 404 error.

If I invert the order of the routes :

```
    Route::get('parkings/filters', 'Api\Parking\ParkingFilterController');
    Route::resource('parkings', 'Api\Parking\ParkingController');
```

It works correctly, but is there a way to do something cleaner ? Like limit `parkings` route ?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue comes from the fact that your resourceful controller uses a GET route `parkings/{parking}` which then matches `filters` and takes priority on the other route.

You can exclude routes from a resourceful controller

```php
Route::resource('parkings', 'Api\Parking\ParkingController')->except([
    'show',
]);
Route::get('parkings/filters', 'Api\Parking\ParkingFilterController');
```

The full documentation is here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes

If you wish a particular treatment with `filters` but still need the other route, you may add a global pattern to your router which will match everything against `{parking}` except `filters`.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#parameters-global-constraints

```php
Route::pattern('parking', '^(?!filters)([a-z0-9-_]+)$');
```

Comment: I think an action is also needed on referring to the controller.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, the fact is I will need `show` route, and yes the global pattern seems nice, but I have many routes... I will check and validate your answer